# making call synchronous in swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to load data form a json file into a table view cell, but the problem is that it loads an empty cell since the data being retrieved has not finished loading. I'm assuming I have to make the call synchronous but am not sure how. Please help!

```
class func getTopAppsDataFromItunesWithSuccess(success: ((iTunesData: NSData) -> Void)) {
    //1
    loadDataFromURL(NSURL(string: TopAppURL)!, completion:{(data, error) -> Void in
        //2
        if ((data) != nil) {
        if let urlData = data {
            //3
            success(iTunesData: urlData)
        }
        }
    })
}


class func loadDataFromURL(url: NSURL, completion:(data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

// Use NSURLSession to get data from an NSURL
let loadDataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if let responseError = error {
        println("error")
        completion(data: nil, error: responseError)
    } else if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {

        if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
            var statusError = NSError(domain:"com.raywenderlich", code:httpResponse.statusCode, userInfo:[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "HTTP status code has unexpected value."])
            completion(data: nil, error: statusError)
        } else {

            completion(data: data, error: nil)
        }
    }
})

loadDataTask.resume()


}
```

Here is where I am making the request

```
class func allCats() -> Array<Animal> {

    var animalArray = Array<Animal>()

       DataManager.getTopAppsDataFromItunesWithSuccess { (iTunesData) -> Void in
...
```

Comment: No need to make it synchronous. One way to do it is to show an activity indicator while the request is proceeding and then in the completion block hide the spinner and reload the table.